# Что такое принцип подстановки Liskov

Tags: c#, solid

Изучаю подходы к SOLID принципам.

Не могу понять, на нормальном примере, что такое принцип подстановки Liskov. Я его понял так, если ваша конструкция использует определенные типы данных, то эта же конструкция должна так же свободно работать с производными от исходного типа, типами. Или я как то не правильно понимаю, подскажите с примером.
Можно ли увидеть самый простой пример из возможных, который иллюстрирует этот принцип

Comment: Почитайте [это](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/10/solid.html), там же есть ссылки на развёрнутое описание каждой буквы из акронима.

Comment: @ixSci я читал это но  мне хочется увидеть нормальный простой пример.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch А можно уточнить, что значит нормальный простой пример. Я просто могу показать всю логику в 20-30 строках синтетического кода для каждого принципа. Или вам надо из продакшена код вытащить с реально работающим в системе кодом?
Можете привести, например, привести вменяемый пример, с вашей точки зрения, для SR или DI принципа? И тогда я вам на подобных примерах опишу Liskov и OC.

Comment: @Axenow Спасибо за ответ, под простым примером я имею ввиду пример наглядный, сколько там строк неважно. Важно видеть логику.

Comment: Вопрос не очень хорошего качества по двум причинам. Во-первых, в одном посте два разных вопроса: старайтесь придерживаться принципа "один вопрос - одна тема". Кто-то может захочет дать ответ только на первую часть, а кто-то на вторую - в итоге в будущем по поиску будет сложнее найти нужные вопросы. Во-вторых, вы не можете сформулировать критерии какой пример именно вам понятен. Вы прочитали двадцать статей с двадцатью примерами? Отлично, значит мы должны найти ещё двадцать (тридцать, сто?) и желательно не попасть в те, что вы уже забраковали. Хороший вопрос имеет чёткие критерии правильности.

Comment: @AK Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Функции, которые используют базовый тип, должны иметь возможность использовать подтипы базового типа, не зная об этом.

Давайте рассмотрим пример на [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

#### Плохой пример

```
public class Bird
{
    public void Fly() { }
}
public class Duck : Bird { }
```

Утка может летать, потому что она *является* птицей. Но что, если есть еще один класс:

```
public class Ostrich : Bird { }
```

Страус - это птица, но она не может летать. `Ostrich` подкласс `Bird` - однако не может использовать метод `Fly`, что означает нарушение LSP.

#### Хороший пример

```
public class Bird { }
public class FlyingBirds : Bird
{
    public void Fly() { }
}
public class Duck : FlyingBirds { }
public class Ostrich : Bird { }
```

<sub>вольный перевод ответа [@MaysaraAlhindi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44913313/2881286)</sub>

Comment: Спасибо отлично, я по другому это представлял. Это круто.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, посмотри другие ответы по ссылке в конце ответа, там есть более подробное описание и еще примеры.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что  под словами Базовый тип имеется ввиду именно классы? Или еще что то?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, определение принципа не привязано к какому-то определенному языку программирования. Если смотреть с точки зрения C#, то _наследоваться_ можно только от класса